# How can I find out the API endpoint for a block producer

Tags: nodeos, cleos, mainnet

Given a list of block producers such as this one:

https://eosportal.io/chain/12/producers

or this one

http://eosnetworkmonitor.io/

How do I figure out the API endpoints that I can connect to with `cleos` to interact with the blockchain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the api endpoint for any BP by querying their `bp.json` file.

The bp.json file has information about the BP publishing it, and among other things it has a key called `api_endpoint` which is what you need.

Every BP should publish their bp.json on their url - copy the web link for the BP you want from http://eosnetworkmonitor.io/ and append `/bp.json` to it.

For example for eosnewyork the bp.json file lives on: http://bp.eosnewyork.io/bp.json.

**PS**: This question was originally asking for a list of endpoints. Leaving the original answer below as a quick reference to some endpoints that should be up.

Every endpoint below should respond to `get info`.

System commands (`cleos system listproducers` for example) may result in errors from some of the nodes. That's by design as some BPs are running their nodes behind firewalls with some functionality disabled/blocked.

---

https://blockmatrix.network/

`cleos -u https://eosapi.blockmatrix.network:443 get info`

---

https://eos.cafe/

`cleos -u http://mainnet.eoscalgary.io:80 get info`

---

http://eosdetroit.io/

`cleos -u https://api.eosdetroit.io:443 get info`

---

https://eosmetal.io/index_en.html

`cleos -u https://api.eosmetal.io:18890 get info`

---

https://www.eosnewyork.io/

`cleos -v -u http://api.eosnewyork.io get info`

---

https://www.eosphere.io/

`cleos -u https://node1.eosphere.io get info`

`cleos -u https://node2.eosphere.io get info`

---

https://eos42.io/

`cleos -u http://nodes.eos42.io:80 get info`

---

http://greymass.com/

`cleos -u https://eos.greymass.com:443 get info`

---

https://www.hkeos.com/

`cleos -u http://api.hkeos.com:80 get info`

---

https://eossweden.se/

`cleos -u https://fn.eossweden.se:443 get info`

---

https://www.saltblock.io/home

`cleos -u https://eos.saltblock.io get info`

---

https://www.worbli.io/

`cleos -u http://eos-api.worbli.io:80 get info`

`cleos -u https://eos-api.worbli.io:443 get info`

---

I have no idea who this belongs to (but it works):

`cleos -u http://185.109.149.236:8888 get info`

Answer (score 1):

http://api.bp.fish works as well. We also have a p2p node up at p2p.bp.fish

Answer (score 1):

We can do this programmatically by utilizing `cleos`, `jq`, `sed`, and `wget`.

First of all, we get a list of all the block producers, and specifically we get the URL for their websites:

`cleos get table eosio eosio producers -l -1 | jq -r '.rows[].url' > bp_url.dat`

Next, we need to add `wget` to each of these URLs

`sed -e 's/^/wget -t 1 --timeout=1 /' -i bp_url.dat`

And finally, we can generate a script to add bp.json to the end of each website from the BPs

`sed -e 's/$/\/bp.json; cat bp.json | jq -r ".nodes[] | select(.node_type == \\\"full\\\") | .api_endpoint"/' bp_url.dat > api_endpoints.sh`

If you run this script, it will download each bp.json file, then print the API endpoints to terminal, you can save the results by doing:

```
chmod +x ./api_endpoints.sh
./api_endpoints.sh > api_endpoints.dat
```